# How to perform Solr performance testing?

Tags: performance, solr, jmeter, load-testing

I got the task to test Solr performance testing. I am completely new to Solr and not having idea how to perform here testing.
Solr which we are using, it is utilizing a lot of RAM and CPU. Due to that our application is getting hang and send server error messages.

What would be the way of testing Solr, whether it is required any tool to create multiple concurrent threads?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Solr Quick Start](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/quickstart.html) guide

> **Searching**
>
> Solr can be queried via REST clients, cURL, wget, Chrome POSTMAN, etc., as well as via the native clients available for many programming languages.

so you can use "usual" [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers to mimic multiple users concurrently using Solr.

References:

- [Building a Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html)
- [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter)

Comment: Sounds good to know the method, can you explain me with any real time scenario. How can I perform testing for Solr using jmeter?

Comment: First of all your load test should simulate anticipated Solr instance(s) usage by real users or applications. Once done you can gradually increase amount of simulated virtual users till response time starts exceeding acceptable threshold or you start receiving errors

Answer (score 1):

For search applications, the amount of requests by itself usually isn't as important as the query profile. There's a lot of internal caching going on, and the only useful way to be able to do decent performance testing, is to use your actual query logs to replicate the query profile that represents your users. You'll also have to use the actual data that you have in your Solr server, so you get (at least) close to the same cardinality for fields and values.

This would mean using the same filters, the same kind of queries and within the same kind of simultaneous load. Since you probably want to go above the load you see in production, using logs for several days as a single day (and be sure to get weekends vs weekdays in there, and if you have a particularly bad day, such as black fridays for ecommerce, keep those logs available so you're able to replicate that profile.

There are (many) tools to do the HTTP requests to Solr, but be sure to use a query profile and sets of queries that actually represent how you're using Solr, otherwise you're just hitting the query cache each single time, or you have data that doesn't represent the actual data in your dataset - which will give you completely irrelevant response times (i.e. random data performs a lot worse than actual english text where tokens are repeated over documents).

Answer (score 1):

> You can use solr meter to do the performance testing. read here [solr
>   meter wiki](https://github.com/tflobbe/solrmeter/blob/wiki/Usage.md)

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing is not how to test the queries - but putting up the scenarios that you want to test and which mimicks the real time application usage you see.

initially you need to decide what you want to find out with your test. Do you want to find bottlenecks? do you want to find out if your current setup can match business requirements? do you need to find the breaking points of your current architecture and setup?

Solr utilizing a lot of CPU is very often related to indexing and memory usage might be related to segment merging - so it sounds like you need to define your senarios.

- how much content should you push to Solr for it to perform indexing?
- how many queries do you need to send?
- what are the features of the queries (facets, highlighting, spellcheck etc)?

Comment: I want to identify the load of the data, which is making app slow. We have huge entries with different entities connected.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Jmeter to test the throughput of your search application and you could also check for IO, load, CPU usage & Ram Usage on each Solr instances.